# How to import references to word file?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have three pages worth of references.

I can not import them into word, at least I can't find a way. Only way to import them is inputting them one by one, which I don't really fancy.

I do not have the folder containing sources.xml, as far as I am aware it does not exist for me. Under applications support > microsoft I do not even have an office folder and search of any other folders with office in it also leads me nowhere.

I was trying to follow [this](https://blogs.office.com/2010/09/29/move-bibliography-sources/) guide as well, but i do not have the Manage Sources icon available either.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if Word has a built in reference manager.  In the past I have been using EndNote, but it will cost money.  You should check out Mendeley (https://www.mendeley.com/).  Once a reference manager is installed, you should see some of those menu items show in in Word.